# assembly reference MySql.Data in web.config not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to put an ASP page on my website that accesses a MySql database. The Website project was built in VS2015 and I used MySql.Data dll version 8.0.11.0 (the latest release).

I hosted the website on localhost on the development machine with IIS server. The web.config file has the following assembly reference which was created by VS -

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">    
  <assemblies>           
    <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>       
  </assemblies>     
</compilation>
```

Everything works fine on the development machine, I can access the database, execute queries, etc.

The problem comes when I upload everything to the hosting server. The assembly reference above causes the following error from the parser -
Parser Error Message:

Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm thinking that the host server may not have this latest version. Could this be the problem, and if so, how should I reference the MySql.Data assembly?

I have looked all over the web, but cannot find anything very specific, would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Try pasting the MySQL.Data dll in your website bin directory

Comment: Mohsin, thank you for responding. There was an existing folder named cgi-bin, so I tried it there but result was same. I made a new folder, bin and tried it there, but again, same result. Is there something I need to do to get the server to look in that folder?

Comment: Mohsin, you were right, but I had to add the bin folder under the httpdocs folder, instead of the root folder. Thanks again very much!!!

Comment: That’s great. I have also posted the fix as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The proposed fix was to paste the MySQL.Data dll in bin folder